Off Grid Without Battery Inverter
Respected Members,
In My Country Pakistan hundreds of peoples selling off grid inverters that are working without battery. But I am not sure whether it is safe or not? because solar production is not constant and as DC current is not constant how the AC frequency is constant? The inverter output voltage also vary too much. they install low voltage relay of 180V for safety just . I think those peoples are selling wrong item. Am I right?

The people are selling what other people are buying... Presumably there would be a lot of angry customers if those inverters were completely useless. They probably are good enough for many uses.

It's possible to run a solar inverter without battery, but if power required by the load is higher than what the PV panels can provide, then it will either shut down or reduce voltage.
So it can be useful for some loads like:

Water heater resistor or other heating elements, which don't care about mains voltage, frequency, or anything else: if the inverter reduces voltage, it will draw less power, so it will adapt to whatever is available.

Low power loads like a cellphone charger, in this case as long as the sun is shining you'll have enough power to run it


But for other loads like an air conditioner or a PC, which either get the power they need or don't work at all, then it's useless. In this case even a small battery is very useful, so your PC doesn't reboot every time there is a cloud passing over the PV panels...
